# Identify this roofing material

Tags: roof, materials

Is this torchdown? Modified bitumen? Or something else?

[image]

Comment: ... what? The surface under the white support base? Where is this? And, why do you care?

Comment: It looks like a  Membrane type to me . The rolled roofing I used to use was black and had overlapped seams that were heated with a torch to make the seal. My current house has similar on an addition, it is ordered by the size of the roof. I ordered some to cover a leaking cargo container 4/5 years ago and it looks the same that is on my new to me house.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I'm talking about the roofing material that the roof is made out of. And I care because I have to repair a leak in it and the methods available depend on the material the roof is made out of.